# Incorrectly positioned CSS

Tags: css

See image below:

[image: Example]

Right now, I have `.tweet_list` on the left and `#tweets_right` on the right, however I would like `#tweets_right` to sit at the top inline with `#tweet_list`.

The CSS is as follows for the both:

```
#tweet_list{
    width: 500px;
    height: 187px;
    background: url(../images/tweet_bg.gif) no-repeat;
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 60px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
}

#tweets_right{
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    color: #818179;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin-right: 60px;
}
```

I could use `margin-top: -100px;` but surely this isn't the best way. I'm new to this, could someone please help?

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: do you use table or divs? If you use divs then something else affect the result because the css you post can't produce the result you posted. The best way to help you is to create an example of the problem at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Thanks, here's the JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/vCZ9q/

Comment: you have an additional `}` in your css. I removed and now the result is this. Because you have big width for the `#tweets` to view it correctly slide the bar that split the result page from the javascript page to the left. You will see that the code is ok. (the left part is downer because you have 30px margin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem happens because your first div is a large width. It extends beyond the width of your browser so the next div gets forced downwards. Try and maximize your browser window and see what happens.

Works for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
/*Setting css properties for body tag*/
body
{

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;

}



#main_container {
    width: 960px;
    background: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto; /*centers the elements*/
}
#tweet_list{
    width: 800px;
    height: 187px;
    background: url(../images/tweet_bg.gif) no-repeat;

    font-family: 'FujitsuSansRegular', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;

 white-space:nowrap;
}

#tweets_right{
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    color: #818179;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin-right: 60px;
    top:0px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="main_container">
<div id="tweets_right">Tweets Right</div>
<div id="tweet_list">Tweet_List</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to wrap these two divs in a container div and then set the width attribute with a reasonable value.

Answer (score 0):

More info about vertical align can be found here: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)

Comment: some things can be done better or in a different way on w3schools but for this subject I think it says what you need to know. I'll keep in mind not to post any links to them though.

Answer (score 0):

there are two methods:

**First:**

always allocate width of both div `Width:50%;`

> With this each div will always only be
> 50% of whatever the wrapping div's
> width is set to:

**Reference:** http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/11273/float-question/p1

**Second: ( u can call trick )**

> Follow the link Greg posted in a
> [comment](http://www.doctype.com/wierd-ie6-float-issue)
> for a working solution. Basically put
> you floating element first in the
> html.